# Matlab: perfcurve scores must be a vector of floating values

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm, roc

The following code throws the error: You must pass scores as a vector of floating-point values.

```
  [Yhat scores] = predict(svmModel, meas );
[X,Y,T,AUC] = perfcurve(Yhat ,scores,'1');
```

Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't provide deep help since I don't know what do you want to achieve exactly. BTW, I found you make a fundamental mistake by using single quotation with number one '1' since it recognized as charter not number. Therefore, it can match nothing with the array of numbers `Yhat`.

You can't use `scores` with two columns since the `perfcurve(_)` accept such a parameter with a single column only.

The code after apply the previous comments

```
% On full data
[Yhat, scores] = predict(svmModel, meas );
[X,Y,T,AUC] = perfcurve(Yhat ,abs(scores(:,2)),1);
plot(X,Y,'LineWidth',3)
xlabel('False positive rate')
ylabel('True positive rate')
title('ROC for Classification ')
```

The above code may not solve your issue but it will guide you to figure out your mistakes.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The error is not there but when I applied it to my actual data I got a weird graph. I have included the ROC plot in the question and can you please see the update which will clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: My label of interest is the abnormal class 1. More true positives for class 1 is preferred. But I am not getting the usual plot signature if I give 1. But if I give 0, I get the other signature.